# andmap in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

In Racket, there is a really useful built in function `andmap` that lets see if a function evaluates to true on every element of a given list, as follows:

```
> (andmap number? (list 2 4 5))
#t
> (andmap number? (list 2 4 "foo"))
#f
```

Is there an equivalent of this in Haskell, or do you have to construct it yourself by using `map` and `reduce`?

Comment: In Haskell lists are homogeneous which means you can not construct a list with elements of different types. So `[2, 4, "foo"]` is a no no. So.. you can not do what exactly you are asking for in Haskell. However as the answers mention `all` should be the closest function to accomplish this task.

Comment: Great point @Redu. I don't actually have a need to do this in Haskell. I just needed a simple example in Racket so people would know what I was talking about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for `all`:

```
> all (>0) [1, 2, 3]
True
> all (>0) [1, -2, 3]
False
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Google wasn't helpful because of the completely different function name I guess...

Comment: [Use Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%3A%3A+%28a+-%3E+Bool%29+-%3E+%5Ba%5D+-%3E+Bool) when you know the type.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson That's awesome! Thanks for the reference.

Comment: @setholopolus there is other good info here https://stackoverflow.com/tags/haskell/info

Comment: @setholopolus Don't use this exact `hoogle` engine. It's horrible. And can find only something simple and very common. But in lot of real-world cases you won't find what you want :( Use search on stackage website: https://www.stackage.org/

Comment: @Shersh it's true that Hoogle doesn't work nearly as well for advanced stuff involving type classes from libraries. But for beginners, it's actually a pretty good help at least for exploring the `base` library.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `all` for this purpose

e.g.

```
> all even [2,4]
True
```